# Can we express the value of $b^a$ in terms of $c$ , where $c=a^b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function, exponentiation

We know that ;

If $a+b = c$, then $b+a = c$

If $a-b = c$ , then $b-a=-c$

If $ab = c$ then $ba = c$

If $\dfrac{a}{b} = c$ then $\dfrac{b}{a} = \dfrac{1}{c}$

Now, I am curious to know that If $a^{b} = c$ , then what is $b^a$ in terms of $c$ ?

I tried using logarithms but failed to get the desired answer in terms of $c$.

---

**EDIT**: It has been made clear from the answers that $b^a$ is not unique because $a^b$ can also be expressed as $x^y$ where $x,y$ can take infinite values. However, what happens if $a$ and $b$ are not changed? I want to emphasize more on the numerical value of $b^a$ rather than preserving numerical value of $a^b$ and then changing it to for some other forms of $x,y$ such that $x^y=c$.

For example, $2^6 = 64$ and $6^2=36$ which is unique. It is clear that $64 = 4^3$ ;***but we do not wish to change $a$ and $b$ by other possible values which also happen to be some solutions of the $c$.***

Or in more mathematical terms, I am intrested in ;

If for some $a,b$ we have :

$a^b = c$ then find $y^x$ given that :

1)$x^y = c$ as well as

2)$x=a$ , $y=b$

If it is impossible to find, then please also provide a proof . Thanks!

Comment: $2^6=64=4^3=8^2.$ But $6^2, 3^4, 2^8$ are all different numbers.

Comment: Are you expecting some function $f(c)$ on the other side? Consider $2^4=16$ and $4^2=16$. This implies that $f(16)$ would have to be $16$. But also $16^1=16$, and yet $1^{16}\neq16$.

Comment: Means there is no general formula?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So how does this answer the question? I also know that  $a^b$ and $b^a$ are also different numbers ( in general) . Also, a/b and b/a are different but we can compute the other if one is given.

Comment: The point is that knowing $a^b$ is not enough information to determine $b^a$. If you know $a^b=64$, then $b^a$ could be $81$ ($3^4$), $36$ ($6^2$), $256$ ($2^8$), or $1$ ($1^64$).

Comment: If $a^b = c$, then $b = \log_a c$, so $b^a = (\log_a c)^a$. If that helps.

Comment: Oh now I understand. Thanks very much Thomas and Karl .

Comment: @Karl Sorry for the confusion once again but I am assuming $a$ and $b$ are known constants. Please read the edited question. .

Comment: @ThomasAndrews   Sorry for the confusion once again but I am assuming a and b are known constants. Please read the edited question. .

Comment: "In terms of $c$" means not in terms of $a$ and $b.$ In terms of $a,b,c$ the value is $b^a,$ so that can't be what you mean.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Means we cannot find a general formula for $b^a$ even if it is given that $b^a$ is unique by providing that $b$ and $a$ are not changed . Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "unique," unless we are only talking about integers $a,b.$ Even then, there is only a unique value for $b^a,$ given $c,$ if any only if $c$ is not an $n$th power for any $n>1.$ Then $b^a=1.$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider $a=1$. Then you have: $a^b=c=1$ holds $\forall b\in\mathbb R$.

Can we determine the value of $b^a=b^1=b\,?$

---

If you're looking for a *"more mathematical"* answer with rigorous constraints, the following method might work for us.

Let $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, such that

$$0<a\neq 1\wedge 0<b\neq 1.$$

Then $\forall m>0$, you have

$$a^b=\left(a^m\right)^\left(\frac bm \right)=c$$

This implies that,

$$b^a:=\left(\frac bm \right)^{a^m}$$

Then, can the value of $\left(\frac bm \right)^{a^m}$ be unique $\forall m>0\,?$

Thus, you have shown that
$b^a$ takes infinitely  many number of different values.

---

**Expanded and more detailed explanation:**

If we cannot define your problem more precisely, we cannot offer a solution.

In this context $a$ and $b$ are fixed real numbers, such that $0<a\neq 1\wedge 0<b\neq 1$ holds. Then, define the number $c$ as $c:=a^b$. We need to find the algebraic function $f:\mathbb R^{+}\longrightarrow \mathbb R^{+}$, such that $f(c):=b^a$ holds. If we define the function $y:=f(c)$, then we consider $c$ as a variable.
Otherwise, your question will lose its mathematical meaning if we don't consider $c$ as a variable. For instance:

$$c=2^3, \; f(c):=3^2$$

or

$$c=5^8,\; f(c):=8^5$$

Observe that, this is obviously impossible to construct the function $f:\mathbb R^{+}\longrightarrow \mathbb R^{+}, \,f(c)$  such that $f(c):=b^a$, where $f(c)$ is an algebraic function, that doesn't involve any of the numbers $a$ or $b$.

*Proof:* Applying the same argument $\forall m>0$ we have,

$$
\begin{align}&\begin{cases}f(c):=f\left(a^b\right)=b^a\\f(c):=f\left(\left(a^m\right)^\left(\frac bm \right)\right)=\left(\frac bm \right)^{a^m}\end{cases}\\
\implies &b^a=\left(\frac bm \right)^{a^m},\forall m>0\\
&\text {A contradiction.}\end{align}
$$

In other words,

$f(c)\equiv b^a\equiv\left(\frac bm \right)^{a^m}$ is *not* unique.

---

**Conclusion:**

> You can not construct the function $f:\mathbb R^{+}\longrightarrow \mathbb R^{+}, \,f(c)$  such that $f(c):=b^a$, where $f(c)$ is a standard mathematical function, that doesn't involve any of the numbers $a$ or $b$.

Remember that, you can easily construct the bivariate function $f(a,c)$ using logarithms.  But,  you can also construct the equivalent function $g(b,c)$ without using logarithms:

$$
\begin{align}&c=a^b\wedge 0<a,b\neq 1\\
\implies &a=c^{\frac 1b}\\
\implies &b^a=b^{c^{1/b}}
\end{align}
$$

Thus, your function can be defined as follows:

$$g:A \longrightarrow \mathbb R^{+},\;\;\;g(b,c):=b^{c^{1/b}}$$

where, $\begin{align}A:=&\left\{(b,c){\large{\mid}} b\in\mathbb R^{+}\setminus \left\{1\right\},\;c\in\mathbb R^{+}\right\}\end{align}$

Comment: No, I cannot determine. Thanks, I understand it now.

Comment: A limitation exists also for the case $\frac{a}{b} = c$ when $a=0$ then $\frac{b}{a}=?$.

Comment: @user The answer is expanded.

Comment: @lonestudent But sir, I have assumed that $a$ and $b$ are constants and not variables. For example, $2^3=8$ but $3^2$ is unique because $2$ and $3$ are constants.

Comment: @An_Elephant  Added expanded and more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks. But can't be define something as $f(a,b) = b^a$ instead of a single valued function. By this, uniqueness will be there.

Comment: I am sorry but please tell that we cannot define $2^\sqrt2$ because it is transcendental and 2 is rational and hence there is no general formula? Thanks

Comment: @An_Elephant  Remember this was just perspective, not proof. See the last part of my answer.  I completed.

Answer (score 4):

$$c = a^b = e^{b\log(a)} \implies \log(c) = b\log(a) \implies $$

$$b = \frac{\log(c)}{\log(a)} \implies b^a = \left[\frac{\log(c)}{\log(a)}\right]^a. $$

---

Alternative expression is that

$$c = a^b \implies b = \log_a(c) \implies b^a = \left[\log_a(c)\right]^a. \tag1 $$

**Note**
The expression in (1) above is *different* from

$$\log_a \left[c^a\right] = a \times \left[\log_a(c)\right].$$

Comment: Thanks . I cannot find reason but please tell that does this contradict the discussion above that $b^a$ is not unique.

Comment: @An_Elephant No contradiction.  All you really know about the values $a,b,c$ is that $a^b = c.$  You can not use this information, by itself, to determine a unique value for $b^a$.

Comment: Means the unique value can only be determined only if $a$ and $b$ are constants? But I haven't assumed in the question that they are variable. So please explain. I am confused again.

Comment: Please see the edited question.

Answer (score 1):

We have that for $a>0$ and $a\neq 1$, $b>0$ and $c>0$

$$a^b=c \iff b=\log_a c \iff b^a =\left(\log_a c\right)^a$$

otherwise it is not invertible in general, as for

$$c=\frac a b \iff \frac b a = \frac 1 c$$

wich requires $b\neq 0$ and $a \neq 0$.