# How to $a^b \to b^a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, transformation

Addition, multiplication and power are formed in a similar way. One follows from the other by repeating the preceding action several times. But while $a+b=b+a$, and $a \times b=b \times a$, in turn $a^b \neq b^a$ - the power action has no commutativity.

So, I'm curious: is it possible to "flip" $a^b$ into $b^a$ by some action? Like for example $a-b=-(b-a)$ or $\frac{a}{b}=1:\frac{b}{a}$. I understand that subtraction and division are sort of the opposite of addition and multiplication (I apologise for not knowing the terminology). That's why I'm curious: is it even possible?

As I understood, because of the lack of this commutativity, the power has a logarithm and a root (and the root is a variation of the power as $\sqrt[b]{a}=a^{\frac 1 b}$). And with the logarithm you can do just that: $\log_b{a}=\frac{1}{\log_a{b}}$.

So it should be clarified that let a and b are numbers that are not powers of other numbers (like prime numbers just for power) to avoid non-uniqueness of the function of interest. Like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4539873/can-we-express-the-value-of-ba-in-terms-of-c-where-c-ab).

Since one number corresponds to exactly one representation by the product of prime multipliers, when we power a number, we are essentially multiplying the power of each prime divisor by the power to which we are do the original number. And we get a new set of prime factors and, as a consequence, a new unique number. Hence the lack of commutativity. And hence the unknowns for me.

What it can mean, how to perform that transformation (if it is possible), and whether I am not mistaken at all? - that's what I'm curious in!

Comment: $64=2^6=4^3$, so should $f(64)$ be $6^2=36$ or $3^4=81$?

Comment: In fancier math language, you might ask it this way: is there an elementary function $F(x,y)$ such that $F(a^b,b^a) = 0$ for all $a$ and $b$ (perhaps restricting to positive numbers or some other subset of the plane)?

Comment: The comment by coiso really nails the problem, and the fundamental difference between exponentiation and other operations like subtraction and division.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang The OP's question is rather: is there a function $f$ such that $f(a^b)=b^a?$ And coiso's comment proves there is none.

Comment: That's a good point, @coiso, then let a and b be such numbers that are not powers of other numbers. So let's not consider cases like $64 = 2^6 = (2^2)^3 = 4^3$ . I have redacted the question.

Comment: Revised, not redacted. All reals are powers of other reals, so I assume you mean integers greater than $1$. Then, given $n$, we can let $b$ be the smallest integer for which $n=b^a$ has an integer solution $a$, and define $f(n)=a^b$. You will not be able to express this with logarithms and algebraic formulas and the like. Note also this won't be self-inverse: $f(3^4)=4^3$ but $f(4^3)=f(2^6)=6^2\ne 3^4$.

Comment: How about $f(x)=1$? Since $x=x^1$, so this sends $x^1$ to $1^x$.